# Posts with a url do not open but link to url

Tags: telescope

When adding posts that have a URL included in the body, the post does not open, rather just the URL. The url is automatically added to the URL field by Telescope. What am I missing setting-wise?

Comment: you need to provide your `html` for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way Telescope (and Hacker News, Reddit, etc.) works. If you provide a URL, the link will take you there.